# Figures on the number of LaTeX users

Tags: latex

I am looking for figures on the number of academics using Tex or LaTeX.

> How may people use LaTeX?

LaTeX is a computer language used to produce pdfs and make books. It is popular across STEM fields.

I am also interested in related figures that people can find or know about. For example:

- What percentage of textbooks are made using LaTeX?
- What percentage of Springer books are made using LaTeX?
- What percentage of mathematicians (physicists, chemists, biologists, engineers, computer scientists, etc.) use LaTeX?

Comment: The TeX SE might be a better place for this.

Comment: And they have this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29236/128923